# How can I give an access user01 to only reset password for user02 in CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, sudo, users, privileges

I am trying to do it via visudo but I have no idea what I should type there. Any hint?

At the beginning I tried to give him full root access to test:

```
root   ALL=(ALL)      ALL
user01 ALL=(ALL)      ALL
```

and then I switched user:

```
su user01
passwd user 02
```

and I get error:

```
passwd: Only root can specify a user name
```

So it is not working but I want user01 to reset the password only for user02. I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sudoers entry gives **user01** full *sudo* rights, meaning you still need to run each command through sudo. If you only want to give **user01** rights to change/reset **user02's** password, then add this to your `/etc/sudoers` file (via `visudo`):

```
user01  ALL=(ALL:ALL)   NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/passwd user02
```

Then have **user01** run `sudo passwd user02`.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are the best!